# RestartLoader in Fragment from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-loadermanager

I'm having a bit of an issue with calling restartLoader() from the outside of a ListFragment. The sequence goes according to Tap an "Add"-button which opens an Activity -> Enter data -> Tap Save, which starts an AsyncTask to store data on a server. Upon a successful data transfer, return to the previous Activity -> Have the Activity call a method in the ListFragment that runs getLoaderManager().restartLoader().

This, without fail, always creates a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ListsFragment{42481238} not attached to Activity"-error. If I move the restartLoader() to onResume it works slightly better, but I have other buttons that directly modifies the data connected to the ListFragments, which still trigger an IllegalStateException no matter what.

Excerpt error message from logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29594): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ListsFragment{42450b18} not attached to Activity
E/AndroidRuntime(29594):        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getLoaderManager(Fragment.java:768)
E/AndroidRuntime(29594):        at testpager.ListsFragment.resetList(ListsFragment.java:122)
```

What am I missing? How can I refresh a ListFragment from a FragmentActivity without triggering this exception?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't refresh your `ListFragment` from the `FragmentActivity`... this goes against both the fundamental design guidelines of both `Fragment`s (which are supposed to be designed for reuse and not tied to any one specific activity) and the `LoaderManager` (which is supposed belongs to a single `Activity` or `Fragment`). You should have your `ListFragment` implement the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>` interface instead.

On a separate note, `Loader`s are supposed to receive notifications when their underlying data source is changed, signalling them to perform a new asynchronous load and return the results back to the callback's `onLoadFinished` method. If you must rely on `restartLoader` to get the most up-to-date data, then you've done something wrong (i.e. your `ContentObserver` is not being notified of the change that would have signaled the `Loader` to requery its data).

Comment: Sorry for my inexcusably late response. My project was put on ice for quite a while but I'm resurfacing it.

Comment: Sorry for my inexcusably late response.
I am actually using LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> and Christians Loader http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider
I tried making an implementation that uses a Loader but not necessarily including an entire content provider since I'll only be running this in my own app. I've read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4245672/975641 and it seems a provider might be overkill for this.
Any thoughts? Might be that this is an entire new question. Just trying to clarify.

Comment: `Commonsware` always talks trash about `ContentProvider`s :P. The argument is that CPs are overkill for applications that don't share their data... I almost agree with this, *BUT* the one thing I really like about the CP + loader combination is that it comes with a global notification system. That is, if you call `setNotificationUri()` on your cursor in the CP query method, and `notifyUri()` in your insert/delete methods, the cursors will be notified of content changes throughout your *entire* application (i.e. no polling required!). There isn't an easy way to do this w/o the ContentResolver.

Comment: There are also a bunch of libraries out there that can automate most of the process of writing a CP for you... so honestly, I don't think writing a CP is really that big of a deal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have Activity A which created a loader that has a menu option to save data through Activity B. Once Activity B has saved the data, you want the loader in Activity A to be restarted... am I right?

If so, try doing this in Activity B:

```
public interface onSavedDataListener { 
     void DoneSavingData(); //add parameters if needed
}
... //Whatever other code you have
 //This method should be called from your AsyncTask onFinished() method
 public void dataSaved() { //add parameters if needed
    onSavedDataListener activity = (onSavedDataListener) getActivity();
    activity.DoneSavingData(); //make sure you add the same parameters as you did above
}
```

Then in Activity A, you would implement the listener

```
public class ActivityA extends ListFragment implements onSavedDataListener {

    ... //your other code here

    //Add the listener function
    public void DoneSavingData() { //make sure any parameters you have get added here
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(id, args, loadercallback);
    }

    ...
```

In essence, you create a listener object in Activity B that is implemented in Activity A. I hope I'm right and that it will help you out...

Comment: BTW, if you are using the support pack for backward compatibility to previous SDKs, you should be calling getSupportLoaderManager() instead...