# Get Cursor finalized without prior close() message even if I use ContentProvider

Tags: database, cursor, android-contentprovider

I use `ContentProvider` but sometimes I get the message written in the title. What is the reason? I read that this message would appear if I closed a database before closing a cursor. I also read that I shouldn't take care of closing the cursor if I use `ContentProvider`

Link: [Closing the database in a ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547461/closing-the-database-in-a-contentprovider)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's true that you don't have to close the database when using ContentProvider, but this doesn't apply for cursors. You must be using `getContentResolver().query()` which returns a cursor. Eventually you will have to close that returned cursor with `.close()`, otherwise you'll get that nasty message.

Answer (score 0):

Use Code like following to run in strict mode

```
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
             .detectDiskReads()
             .detectDiskWrites()
             .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
             .penaltyLog()
             .build());
     StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
             .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
             .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
             .penaltyLog()
             .penaltyDeath()
             .build());
```

This starts producing on closable things etc. Hence helps in debugging where the error arose from.

Source : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html