# Sharing data between Runnable and Activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my main activity I start an AlarmManager. The Intent of this AlarmManager is a class which extends BroadcastReceiver. Now, in this BroadcastReceiver class I execute an AsyncTask in the `onReceive()` method. The `doInBackground()` method of this AsyncTask calls a method which starts a new instance of a Runnable. And in the `run()` method of this Runnable I do some data polling and save the data to SharedPreference and/or an SQLiteDatabase.

Back in my main activity I want to know these values that have been read and saved. This works fine for *some* values. I read by using SharedPreferences and/or the SQLiteDatabase.

I can see that when one value changes (the polling thread is reading values that change every 5 minutes, the correct value is stored in the database, but when I read it afterwards in the main activity I just get the old value.

Here's an example of what I do:

I have a helper class called Util. This is called from the `run()` method:

```
Util.storeT1(db, <float value>);
```

Here's the method:

```
public static void storeT1(DBAdapter db, float value) {
    db.open();
    long id = 0;
    id = db.insertFloat("T1", value);
    if (id == -1) { // if error
    }
    db.close();     
}
```

In the main activity, I do:

```
float val = Util.getT1(db);
```

Here's the method:

```
public static float getT1(DBAdapter db) {
    float i = 0;
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.get("T1");
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            i = c.getFloat(0);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return i;
}
```

In the above, `db` is an instance of my DBAdapter class, which is a class handling the database. Relevant methods:

```
public Cursor get(String column) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { column },
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public long insertFloat(String key, Float value) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(key, value);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

**So**, how do I share data correctly between the Runnable and my Activity? I have a feeling it's because of the multiple threads, but I don't know how to fix this.

**Edit:**

I should mention that when I do this:

```
float val = Util.getT1(db);
```

I get the value 0.0, not the value saved from the Runnable.

Comment: I would highly recommend using [content providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html) with [loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Comment: @LaiVung, Loaders is introduced in 3.0, I need to have 2.2 support.

Comment: Then I'd highly recommend [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). Content providers and loaders *did* save a lot of my time, so I hope they will save your time too.

Comment: @LaiVung Do you have any good examples on how to use Content Providers? There are a lot on the web but they all assume that data should be accessed from _other_ apps, which is not the case here.

Comment: I started with `[android-sdk]/samples/android-17/SearchableDictionary`. It just implements `query()` method, but it could help you start. After that you can run an emulator, there are some examples in `App` > `Loader`. The sources are located at `[android-sdk]/samples/android-17/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/Loader*.java`. Finally I hope the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) could help you.

Comment: Also while working with content providers, you don't need to close the instance of DB, [according to Dianne Hackborn](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/NwDRpHUXt0U/jIam4Q8-cqQJ) (Android framework engineer). Here is the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547461/closing-the-database-in-a-contentprovider) on SO.